# Create view in Hive with spaces in column names

Tags: hive

In Hive 0.7, is there any way to create a view with spaces in the column name? In SQL Server I'd do:

```
CREATE VIEW test_vw
AS 
SELECT col_name as [col name with spaces]
FROM   test_tbl;
```

Is there a hive equivalent?

We need the view with names for use by end user tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL):

> In Hive 0.12 and earlier, only alphanumeric and underscore characters
>   are allowed in table and column names.
>
> In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character
>   (see HIVE-6013). Any column name that is specified within backticks
>   (`) is treated literally

Comment: That states that for tables, but not explicitly for views. That quote is from the table section of the Hive doc. But seems to apply to views as well.

Comment: Somehow I was able to create spaces in the column names, but it does not seem to pick up case sensitivity and puts all to lower case

Comment: @ClumZZZey How ?

Comment: Like stated in the answer above and below, with the column names in tickmarks:
`CREATE VIEW spaces_and_capitals
AS 
SELECT 1 as ``COL name with $pace$``
;

+-----------------------+------------+----------+
|       col_name        | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------------------+------------+----------+
| col name with $pace$  | int        |          |
+-----------------------+------------+----------+
`

Comment: Single `  instead of double ``

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
CREATE VIEW test_vw
AS 
SELECT col_name as `col name with spaces`
FROM   test_tbl;
```